# 3rd party jquery-ui install with angular-cli

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli for my angular2 project. In my project I want to use jquery-ui. I installed jquery-ui with

```
npm install jquery jquery-ui
```

I edited my angular-cli-build.js

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
          'jquery/src/jquery.js',
          'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

How it will update automatically in my dist/vendor folder , Do I need to add the css files (like css/jquery-ui.css) in my index.html like ?

I have followed the moment.js integration from this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-material2-to-your-project) but it didnt help with jquery-ui.
 I will appreciate a working example of jquery-ui integration with angular-cli

Comment: Yes, you will need to add css files into index.html, unless you bundle styles with webpack or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In your angular-cli-build.js put like :

```
'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', </i>
```

Then in your system.config.ts :

```
const map: any = {
'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
'jquery.ui': 'vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

importing scripts in angular-cli.json file is the better approch. By you can avoid issues during production deployment.

```
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"'vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work as mentioned in the above approach when you add .js files in the scripts section in the angular-cli.json file.

With that please add this to your main module class and check whether it is working.

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```