# Loading jQuery-UI using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng

Using the Angular CLI, I am trying to load JQuery-UI in my Angular 2 application (for PrimeNG's Datepicker). However, it appears that SystemJS is not loading the JQuery-UI libs.

After building, the JQuery-UI libs are successfully store in the /dist directory: 
[image]

as a result of the following Angular-cli-build.js configuration:

```
'jquery-ui-dist/external/jquery/*',
'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js'
```

I tried the following configurations in system-config.ts, but at runtime the network traffic doesn't indicate the libs were requested and the datapicker indicates jQuery is not defined.

System Config #1: (similar to [3rd party jquery-ui install with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524979/3rd-party-jquery-ui-install-with-angular-cli))

```
const map: any = {
'jquery':'vendor/jquery-ui-dist/external/jquery/jquery.js',
'jquery-ui':'vendor/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js'
};
```

SystemJS Config #2:

```
const map: any = {  
'jquery':'vendor/jquery-ui-dist/external',
'jquery-ui':'vendor/jquery-ui-dist/'
};

const packages: any = {
'jquery':{ defaultExtension : 'js'},
'jquery-ui':{ defaultExtension : 'js', main:'jquery-ui.min.js'}
};
```

Any suggestions on how to load JQuery-UI via SystemJS?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this : 
  [script regular expression in angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qyAp.png)

Then in your system-config.ts :
  [system-config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPHY3.png)

if you want to use /primeng/#/calendar let me know because you need to load the 'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon' too :)